# Problem with font special characters in PDF generated from jsPDF + html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf, html2canvas

I have JS code like below, to generate PDF from my website, using jsPDF (https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) and html2canvas (https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas). Everyhing works fine, except special characters (e.g. ółńćźżąś) - are not displayed and text with special characters is damaged.

```
const {
  jsPDF
} = window.jspdf;

let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [1920, 1358]);
let pdfjs = document.querySelector('#content-to-convert');

doc.html(pdfjs, {
  callback: function(doc) {
    doc.save("offer.pdf");
  },
  x: 12,
  y: 12
});
```

I tried to add my own font (using fontconverter from jsPDF) and when I'm generating text it's working, text is in my font and special characters are displayed properly.

```
const {
  jsPDF
} = window.jspdf;

var myFont = 'AAEAAAATAQAA...FiAAwAAAAAAAAAAA==';

let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [1920, 1358]);
let pdfjs = document.querySelector('#content-to-convert');

doc.addFileToVFS("MyFont.ttf", myFont);
doc.addFont("MyFont.ttf", "MyFont", "normal");
doc.setFont("MyFont");

doc.text("font test ółńćźżąś", 12, 12);
doc.save('offer.pdf');
```

But when I'm generating PDF from HTML, my font is not respected and is used Helvetica (the default one as I think), which does not have these special characters.

```
const {
  jsPDF
} = window.jspdf;

var myFont = 'AAEAAAATAQAA...FiAAwAAAAAAAAAAA==';

let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [1920, 1358]);
let pdfjs = document.querySelector('#content-to-convert');

doc.addFileToVFS("MyFont.ttf", myFont);
doc.addFont("MyFont.ttf", "MyFont", "normal");
doc.setFont("MyFont");

doc.html(pdfjs, {
  callback: function(doc) {
    doc.save("offer.pdf");
  },
  x: 12,
  y: 12
});
```

I would prefer to use Google Font - Open Sans, which I use also on the website, but my own converted font also would be ok.